# Formatting tables in markdown blocks: how to use "renderer"?

Tags: tables, formatting, packages, markdown

As you can see, this is similar to [that quesion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599766/formatting-pipe-tables-using-the-markdown-package). However I think my problem has not been solved and then open this.

I'm using `markdown` package in my `LaTeX` document and it works well. However I find my tables always float to the top of my page after I add caption, just like that；

[image: test1]

So I have to disable the float property. I find the `markdown.sty` file:

[image: sty]

then find `table` label and put `[htbp]` after it. Then it works!

[image: test2]

Now I know where is the problem. However it is not a good solution indeed. Then I read [user manual](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.html) and find `Table Renderer` setting. It says:

> 2.3.1.21 Table Renderer

> The \markdownRendererTable macro represents a table. This macro will only be produced, when the pipeTables option is enabled. The macro receives the parameters {⟨caption⟩}{⟨number of rows⟩}{⟨number of columns⟩} followed by {⟨alignments⟩} and then by {⟨row⟩} repeated ⟨number of rows⟩ times, where ⟨row⟩ is {⟨column⟩} repeated ⟨number of columns⟩ times, ⟨alignments⟩ is ⟨alignment⟩ repeated ⟨number of columns⟩ times, and ⟨alignment⟩ is one of the following......

> LATEX Example
> Using a text editor, create a text document named document.tex with the following content:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pipeTables, tableCaptions]{markdown}
\newcount\rowCounter
\newcount\columnCounter
\makeatletter
\def\processRow#1{%
  \columnCounter=1%
  \ifnum\rowCounter=0\relax
    As for the alignment,
  \else
    In row \the\rowCounter,
  \fi
  \processColumn#1
  \advance\rowCounter by 1\relax
  \ifnum\rowCounter>\rowTotal\relax
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi\processRow}%
\def\processColumn#1{%
  column number \the\columnCounter{}
  \ifnum\rowCounter=0\relax
    \if#1d{}has default alignment\fi
    \if#1l{}is left-aligned\fi
    \if#1c{}is centered\fi
    \if#1r{}is right-aligned\fi
  \else
    says \emph{#1}%
  \fi
  \advance\columnCounter by 1\relax
  \ifnum\columnCounter<\columnTotal\relax, \fi
  \ifnum\columnCounter=\columnTotal\relax, and \fi
  \ifnum\columnCounter>\columnTotal\relax
    .\expandafter\@gobble
  \fi\processColumn}%
\makeatother
\markdownSetup{
  renderers = {
    table = {%
      This is a table with caption \emph{#1} that is #3 colums wide
      and #2 rows long.
      \rowCounter=0%
      \def\rowTotal{#2}%
      \def\columnTotal{#3}%
      \processRow
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |

  : Demonstration of pipe table syntax
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

> A PDF document named document.pdf should be produced and contain the following text:
>
> > This is a table with caption Demonstration of pipe table syntax that is 4 colums wide and 4 rows long. As for the alignment, column number 1 is right-aligned, column number 2 is left-aligned, column number 3 has default alignment, and column number 4 is centered. In row 1, column number 1 says Right, column number 2 says Left, column number 3 says Default, and column number 4 says Center. In row 2, column number 1 says 12, column number 2 says 12, column number 3 says 12, and column number 4 says 12. In row 3, column number 1 says 123, column number 2 says 123, column number 3 says 123, and column number 4 says 123. In row 4, column number 1 says 1, column number 2 says 1, column number 3 says 1, and column number 4 says 1.

Urr......I think my level of TeX is not sufficient to understand how it turn the table into a "mess" .

Then I tried copying codes in `markdown.sty` to my LaTeX file with `\makeatletter` command, but it failed.

It seems much more difficult than `image` renderer. To change the `image` renderer I just need to put below into my file:

```tex
\markdownSetup{                                     
  renderers = {    
    image = {\begin{figure}[htb]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width = .9\linewidth]{#3}% 
      \ifx\empty#4\empty\else
        \caption{#4}\label{fig:#1}%
      \fi
    \end{figure}}
  }                                               
}
```

It is easy and clear...but I don't know how `table` renderer works. Maybe I need to write much more code to achieve that.

ps: here is a simple test file:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\markdownSetup{pipeTables = true}                   
\markdownSetup{tableCaptions = true}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
# markdown

markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown 
markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown
markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown 


| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |

: table 1
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Some examples are better so that I can understand and learn more.

Thanks for your reading and answer!

---

## Edit

As the answers say, we can copy codes from `markdown.sty` to our files. However don't put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` at wrong position. They should be put outside `\markdownSetup`, just like that:

```tex
\makeatletter 
\markdownSetup{
  renderers = {
    table = {%
    \markdownLaTeXTable={}%
    \markdownLaTeXTableAlignment={}%
    \markdownLaTeXTableEnd={%
      \markdownLaTeXBottomRule
      \end{tabular}}%
    \ifx\empty#1\empty\else
      \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{%
        \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering\caption{#1}\vspace{3pt}}%
      \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTableEnd{%
        \end{table}}%
    \fi
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{\begin{tabular}}%
    \markdownLaTeXRowCounter=0%
    \markdownLaTeXRowTotal=#2%
    \markdownLaTeXColumnTotal=#3%
    \markdownLaTeXRenderTableRow
    }, 
    link = {\href{#3}{#1}},
    image = {\begin{figure}[htb]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width = .9\linewidth]{#3}%
      \ifx\empty#4\empty\else
        \caption{#4}\label{fig:#1}%
      \fi
    \end{figure}}
  }                                               
}
\makeatother
```

If you are making templates, you don't need to add the two commands.

---

Answer (score 4):

You can specify that LaTeX should not make tables float:

```latex
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\fps@table}{H}
\makeatother
```

This way, you can avoid the redefinition of [the table renderer](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.html#table-renderer).

Comment: Ohhhhh, that is a good idea! At least partly solve my problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To follow the approach described in the question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\markdownSetup{pipeTables = true}                   
\markdownSetup{tableCaptions = true}
\makeatletter
\markdownSetup{renderers={
  table = {%
    \markdownLaTeXTable={}%
    \markdownLaTeXTableAlignment={}%
    \markdownLaTeXTableEnd={%
      \markdownLaTeXBottomRule
      \end{tabular}}%
    \ifx\empty#1\empty\else
      \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{%
        \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering}%
      \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTableEnd{%
        \caption{#1}
        \end{table}}%
    \fi
    \addto@hook\markdownLaTeXTable{\begin{tabular}}%
    \markdownLaTeXRowCounter=0%
    \markdownLaTeXRowTotal=#2%
    \markdownLaTeXColumnTotal=#3%
    \markdownLaTeXRenderTableRow
  }
}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
# markdown

markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown 
markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown
markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown markdown 


| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |

: table 1
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It worked！ I know why I failed: I put all these code `table = ...` into `renderers = { ... }`  as user-manual says. However they should be put into `rendererPrototypes={...}` as `markdown.sty` does.

Now I can control it !

Cheers！

Comment: @yfzhao20: That's likely not why it failed, but it's difficult to check since you didn't provide a working example in your original question. As a user, you should redefine renderers, not renderer prototypes. Renderer prototypes are defined by packages and provide defaults.

Comment: @yfzhao20 indeed the code in my answer also works when using `renderers` instead of `rendererPrototypes`. I have edited the answer because `renderers` seems a cleaner way of doing the definition as Witiko points out.

Comment: The main reason why `renderers` is shorter than `rendererPrototypes`: to discourage the use of the latter. 

Comment: After rechecking I know what happened: I put `\makeatletter` and `makeatother` at wrong position. They should not be put into `\markdownSetup{...}`. Now I am creating templates and it seems they are needless. 

Comment: Indeed, you should not need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. If you do need them, because you are using a command with `@` in its name, then the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should go around `\markdownSetup{...}`, not inside it, so that the commands with `@` are correctly tokenized.