# Newline in table cell possible?

Tags: tables, lyx, line-breaking

I am trying to add linebreaks in my table cell but found that LyX doesn't allow me to. How can I insert a newline inside a table cell?

Comment: If you want to specify the width of the cell: [How to break a line in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table). If you just want to break the line without specifying a width: [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

go into the menu of the tabular (right mouse click when cursor is inside the tabular) and then choose a width for the column. Then you can have linebreaks inside this cell with `\newline` or with an empty line for a new paragraph.

The width setting can be found on right-click > More > Settings > Column Settings > Width (LyX 2.1.4).

Comment: Once the width has been defined, the useful shortcut for a `linebreak` is `ctrl+shift+enter`.

Comment: @landroni in latest versions of Lyx it seems the shortcut is no longer necessary, a simple `enter` is enough to do a linebreak.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, the width thing works well, but I am unable to use either ctrl+enter or enter if I want to do it manually. It shows 'command disabled' at the bottom of the LyX editor. I have LyX 2.2.3 on Windows 7. Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that you have write access to the file?

Comment: @Herbert I am not sure I understand your comment. I am editing the LyX file and can save it. I, therefore, think I have write access to the file.
I was wondering if it was possible to 're-enable' this command in LyX, so I clicked on 'reconfigure' in the menu. I restarted LyX but still did not work.

Comment: @user89073 I thought had the same problem as you (LyX 2.2.3 on Ubuntu). But indeed when you fix the width you can use linebreaks in the usual way.