# LyX table new line

Tags: tables, lyx, columns

While inside a table, it seems impossible to use Ctrl+Enter in order to start a new line in the same column. So if I have, for example, a column name "veni, vidi, vici" and I don't want it to be so wide, I would be able to write it:

```
veni
vidi
vici
```

one word under the other. Anybody knows how to do it with LyX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to give the column where you want to do this a fixed width — right-click the cell, select `More | Settings` and in the pop-up dialogue enter a reasonable value in width. I have, for your example, set it to 2 cm.

If you have Lyx ≥ 2.0.4, you can just type <kbd>Enter</kbd> now.

Otherwise, without space, `Insert | Tex Code` right after veni. In the field that appears, type `\linebreak` with, importantly, a space after the box. Repeat the same for vidi. The job should be done.

[image: LyX]   [image: PDF]

Using `\newline` as suggested by @Vitaly also allows new lines, but indents the last line and moves off the center:

[image: LyX_2]  [image: PDF_2]

Answer (score 0):

Also a `\newline` can be used. 
A quite similar question was asked here: [newline in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26737/newline-in-table-cell-possible)

Comment: `\newline` distorts the alignment of the three words

Comment: Spot on;) Interestingly, it works even without LaTeX command inserted. Simple Return does the job in LyX 2.0.4 after the column width is set to be fixed.

Comment: -> @ Vitaly: Should have checked that first... - with simple Return, alignment remains intact, so clearly the best choice, if the OP has LyX 2.0.4 or better

Comment: Interesting... I tried Enter at first but it won't work. I have LyX 2.0.0. It's good to know they added this simple option... Thank you!