# How to do a line break in a table entry?

Tags: tables, lyx, line-breaking

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26737/newline-in-table-cell-possible) but it is not intuitive at all and it's 6 years old. So, I wonder if the answer by gaborous is correct as I am using Lyx 2.2.2 and simple enter does not do the job for me:

> @landroni in latest versions of Lyx it seems the shortcut is no longer
>   necessary, a simple enter is enough to do a linebreak. – gaborous May
>   31 '16 at 20:54

Is there an easier way to do this? Is the answer by **gaborous** correct in any circumstance?

Comment: It's not clear what you're having problems with. You need to select a column and goto Edit->Table Settings and enter an explicit width for that column.  Then a simple enter will put linebreaks in the table cells.  But you *must* specify a width for the column for this to work.

Comment: The code can use the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in standard `r, c, l` columns. See  my answer to (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

Comment: @Bernard Given that this is a LyX question, that solution is many steps away in LyX. (Not undoable, but not able to be done through regular LyX menu functions, which is the whole idea of LyX.)

Comment: @AlanMunn: That's precisely why  I only commented, as a work around if no one  on this site can explain how this functionality of makecell is included in the menus of LyX (which I don't know).

Comment: @Bernard It's not included in LyX; you'd need to inject explicit LaTeX code into the document.