# How do I put "complex" multiline things as 1 cell in a table?

Tags: tables

Trying to group up different multi line formulas and text that I have to make space on the page, my first thought was to place them as a cell in a table, but trying to do that naively does not work

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}
    \textbf{Removing Left Recursion}

    $A \rightarrow A \alpha\ |\ \beta$\\
    then\\
    $A \rightarrow \beta A^{'}$\\
    $A \rightarrow \alpha A^{'}\ |\ \epsilon$\\
&
    \textbf{Left Factor}

    $A \rightarrow \alpha \beta_{1}\ |\ \alpha \beta_{2}$\\
    then\\
    $A \rightarrow \alpha \beta^{'}$\\
    $\beta^{'} \rightarrow \beta_{1}\ |\ \beta_{2}$ 
\\
\end{tabular}
```

How can I group these things up to take less space?

Comment: Please, can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem so people can help you better.

Comment: I fear that is not enough information to give a viable answer. You have a single column document? Do the multiline math environments span over the whole column horizontally? Why do you hope that placing them in a table saves space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to break a line in a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table)

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual table code. This is a double column document. These are pretty short formulas, so grouping them next to each other will save space and still be readable.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to compress those lines into a narrow table? or do you want to put those grammars side by side?

Comment: I want to put them side by side in a different column but in the same row of a table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I change your table to two columns. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \textbf{Removing Left Recursion} & \textbf{Left Factor}\\
    $A \rightarrow A \alpha\ |\ \beta$ & $A \rightarrow \alpha \beta_{1}\ |\ \alpha \beta_{2}$\\
    then & then\\
    $A \rightarrow \beta A^{'}$ & $A \rightarrow \alpha \beta^{'}$\\
    $A \rightarrow \alpha A^{'}\ |\ \epsilon$ & $\beta^{'} \rightarrow \beta_{1}\ |\ \beta_{2}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: *facepalm* this is so obvious now. Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on a table you can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\textbf{Removing Left Recursion}
\[A\rightarrow A\alpha\mid\beta \quad\text{ then } \begin{cases}A\rightarrow\beta A’\\A\rightarrow\alpha A’\mid\epsilon\end{cases}\]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
\textbf{Left Factor}
\[A\rightarrow\alpha\beta_1\mid\alpha\beta_2 \quad\text{then } \begin{cases}A\rightarrow\alpha\beta\\\beta’\rightarrow \beta_1\mid\beta_2\end{cases}\]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]