# Multiline in a table cell

Tags: tables

I have a problem with my table. I should put a big text in a cell. it should be multi line. How can I do that:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c} 
\hline 
\\
Case & Entscheidungsbäume & Neuronale Netze & kNN & SVM \\ 
\hline\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\\
Accuracy in general & ** & *** & ** & **** \\ % 
Speed of learning with 
respect to number of 
attributes and the number of 
instances  & *** &* & **** & * \\
3 & 31 & 25 & 415 \\
4 & 35 & 144 & 2356 \\
5 & 45 & 300 & 556 \\ [1ex] % 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} % title of Table
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text

\end{table}
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169262/34120

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest you (a) switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment, (b) set the overall width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`, and (c) use a (modified form of) the `X` column type for the first column. Doing so tells LaTeX to calculate the width of the first column as the difference between `\textwidth` and the sum of the widths of the other columns.

In addition, consider doing your readers a favor by using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of the basic-LaTeX `\hline` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro (allows hyphenation)
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Y c c c c @{}} % use 'Y' for first column
\toprule
Case & Entscheidungsbäume & Neuronale Netze & kNN & SVM \\
\midrule
Accuracy in general & ** & *** & ** & **** \\ \addlinespace
Speed of learning with
respect to number of
attributes and number of
instances  & *** &* & **** & * \\ \addlinespace
3 & 31 & 25 & 415 \\
4 & 35 & 144 & 2356 \\
5 & 45 & 300 & 556 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} 
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up questions:

1. My advice would be to avoid double lines; they reek of the 1970s and 1980s... If you want to make the lines created by `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` a bit thicker, you can do so by changing the value of the parameter `\heavyrulewidth`. Its default value is `0.08em`; try, say, `\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.1em}` and see if you like the result. The width of `\midrule` is governed by the parameter `\lightrulewidth` (default value: 0.05em); see if `\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.625em}` works for you. By the way, if you  *insist* on having two consecutive rules, `\toprule\toprule`, `\midrule\midrule`, etc will get the job done...
2. I assume that by having "stars in the middle of each cell" you mean that the asterisks should be centered vertically. (The asterisks are, of course, already centered horizontally.) In this regard my advice is, yet again, "don't do it." :-) Instead, you may want to consider making columns 2 and 3 *narrower* by introducing line breaks in the headers. By making columns 2 and 3 less wide, column 1 automatically becomes wider, and the lengthy text in one of the cells now fits in three rows instead of five. The effect is shown below -- I think that it's no longer useful to think about repositioning the asterisks. (If you still insist on vertically centering the asterisks, issue the instruction `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` after loading the `tabularx` package and before setting up the `Y` column type...)

Just for fun I've also augmented the values of `\heavyrulewidth` and `\lightrulewidth` by 25% in the following image, per the discussion in the first bullet point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro (allows hyphenation)
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros 

\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.1em}
\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.0625em}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} Y c c c c @{}} % use 'Y' for first column
\toprule
Case & Entscheidungs- & Neuronale & kNN & SVM \\ %% new: line breaks in two of the header cells
& bäume & Netze\\
\midrule
Accuracy in general & ** & *** & ** & **** \\ \addlinespace
Speed of learning with
respect to number of
attributes and number of
instances  & *** &* & **** & * \\ \addlinespace
3 & 31 & 25 & 415 \\
4 & 35 & 144 & 2356 \\
5 & 45 & 300 & 556 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} 
\label{table:nonlin}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have two questions (1) how can I have double thick line instead of one thick line? and (2) I want to have stars in the middele of each cells? how can I modified this beatiful code to do that?

Comment: @Kaja - I've posted an addendum to address your follow-up questions. As you'll see, I suggest *not* adjusting the vertical positions of the asterisks but to redistribute the widths of columns 1, 2, and 3 in a straightforward way. By making column 1 wider, the lengthy material in one of the cells no longer occupies 5 but only 3 rows. If you make this change, I believe it's no longer necessary or useful to fiddle with the vertical position of the asterisks.

Comment: Does "tabularx" require any additional package? Thanks please let me know --  I have trouble to compile the file. Can one include both "tabular" and "tabularx" in the \usepackage{tabularx} and \usepackage{tabular}?

Comment: @wonderich - The `tabular` environment is provided by the LaTeX "kernel", i.e., no extra package needs to be loaded in order to make use of it. There is no `tabular` package. The `tabularx` environment may be accessed by loading the `tabularx` package; to wit, note the statement `\usepackage{tabularx}` in the preamble shown above.

Comment: @Micro can we limit each column length? I have tried `C{2.3cm}` but it did not help

Comment: @alperd - Absolutely not. At least one of the table's columns must be of type `X`.

Answer (score 24):

The p attribute should help.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} c c c c}
```

Comment: Looked easier than the excepted answer. So I tried it and it works like a charm.