# Newline in a table cell which is centered

Tags: tables, line-breaking

This question may look like a duplicate but, none of the answers given to the possible duplicates contain the answer to this specific case.

I have a tabular, say `\begin{tabular}{ccc}`. While adding a new line to a cell, I want both resulting lines to be horizontally centered. Is there an elegant solution to this? If not is there a solution to this?

Comment: Actually, (at the moment) answers in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2441/250119 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/250119 works well.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

How about using `\shortstack` inside a cell?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    one & two & three \\
    one & two & \shortstack{a \\ bb \\ c}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this worked like a charm, why didn't I see anyone mentioning this before? Simple, straightforward solution.

Comment: +1 for `\shortstack`.

Comment: +1 And to align the content, use `\shortstack[r]{...}` (r = right align, l = left align, c = center align).

Comment: How to _vertically_ align the content using `\shortstack`?

Comment: @hengxin wrap the shortstack in a `\multirow` and then adjust like you would a multirow

Answer (score 19):

This is an old thread, but there is a new solution.

```
\usepackage{makecell}
%% tablestart
...
\makecell{line 1 \\ line2}
%% tableend
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10):

If you want the cells to be centered horizontally as well as vertically I suggest the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\bigcell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
a & \bigcell{c}{this schould be a longer line \\ this is a shorter one} & c \\ 
\midrule
 0,9892 & 0,9892 & 0,9892  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: All answers given work, but I prefer this one as it gives adequate spacing at the top of a table cell (instead of touching the cells top line).

Comment: Is there a way to decrease the vertical space between the lines in the cell? Using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}` inside the `bigcell` definition leads to a bad looking vertical alignment.

Answer (score 4):

Another way I discovered is to use `matrix`. Not as simple as Christian's answer but provides vertical alignment along columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    one & two & three \\
    one & two & $\begin{matrix} \text{a} \\ \text{bb} \\ text{c} \end{matrix}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{ccc}
    one & two & three \\
    one & two & {a \\ bb \\ c}\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `\parbox` like this:

```
\parbox[c][][c]{width}{\centering very long \\ line}
```

This has an advantage over `\shortstack` when also using `\rowcolors` to color table rows with alternating colors. `\parbox` results in a cell that has a single consistent color, and the next table row will have the alternative color. However, using `\shortstack` leads to two consecutive rows with the same color.

Comment: A similar solution was proposed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55860/any-way-to-center-text-within-a-parbox/55861#55861

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
    one & two & three \\
    one & two & \Block[t]{}{a \\ bb \\ c}\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]