# Any way to center text within a \parbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, paragraphs

Probably I'm missing something, but I'm really struggling to find an answer to this simple question:

How to center text within a `\parbox`?

Side note: I don't want to switch to any other environment like `minipage`. In particular, I use `\pbox`, an auto-sizing version of `\parbox`. There don't seem to be an analogue for `minipage`.

---

Ok, so `\centering` as presented in one of the posts is working for the given simple example. I'm however somehow unable to adapt it to my concrete case that is:

```
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
...

\pbox{1\textwidth}{
  \AxiomC{$ Rule premise $}
  \UnaryInfC{$ Rule conclusion $}
  \DisplayProof (Rule name) \\
  Some text here in new line
}
```

---

It seems `\pbox` indeed works differently with respect to `\centering` than `\parbox`. In particular this works:

```
\usepackage{bussproofs}
...

\parbox{1\textwidth}{\centering
  \AxiomC{$ Rule premise $}
  \UnaryInfC{$ Rule conclusion $}
  \DisplayProof (Rule name) \\
  Some text here in new line
}
```

I'll probably have to use the original `\parbox` after all or perhaps switch to a `varwidth`.

---

I thank you all for your help. I think I'll be able to solve my issue somehow using a combination of the ideas that you presented.

Comment: only 1 of the five commands you show in your edit is defined in standard latex. If we have no idea how the commands are defined we can't say why they don't work. Please edit again to make a complete example using as few packages as possible (preferably just the one that defines pbox) that shows the problem.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I'll try to improve on that.

Comment: You probably need neither `\pbox` nor `varwidth` but a plain `tabular`. Without knowing more details about your macros it's difficult to say more. Please write down a *complete* minimal example of usage.

Comment: Yes, tabular is possible as well. For now, I think I'll manage. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please try to avoid EDIT headers. Simply update you posts to reflect the latest version. Your third edit for example could have been easily added to the  sentence were you first talk about `\pbox`. If required you can add `----` to get a visible separator.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of the etiquette. I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

just use `\centering` inside the box.

```
\parbox{2cm}{\centering
  one two three four five six}
```

I assume you are using this package, so with some limitations you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

\parbox{2cm}{\centering
  one two three four five six eight nine ten
aaaaaa\\
bbb}

\bigskip

\pbox{5cm}{\relax\ifvmode\centering\fi
  one two three four five six eight nine ten\\
aaaaaa\\
bbb}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried and I got errors. Could you please give an example of how it should be used properly?

Comment: code added as requested, did you try `\parbox` or your `\pbox` which might be (and probably is) completely different. You may need to post a small complete document showing which package you load.

Comment: Oh ok. Can I have multiple lines with `\centering`?

Comment: yes that makes three centred lines at normal font sizes. Or you can linebreak manually with `\\ ` all as usual.

Comment: Ok, the issue seems to be more complex than I thought. Your solution works for the outlined example, however if possible, please see my edit.

Comment: Great solution, even if it's somewhat mystical to me! `\relax\ifvmode\centering\fi` works perfectly.

Answer (score 14):

There is the `varwidth` environment from the package with the same name, which is an auto-sizing version of `minipage`. You only need to give a maximal width.

The text centering inside it or inside `\parbox` can and should be done using `\centering`.