# Troubles with Tables

Tags: tables

I'm not exactly sure how to format my LaTeX code for this website. So maybe someone can help me with that... I'm having trouble with a table in LaTeX:

1. In the cell that says "Dimension of Sample", the text goes outside the box.
2. I would like the 1,2,3 of the sample dimensions to be centered in the cells vertically
3. I would like the main portion of the table entries to be left aligned without affecting the alignment for the rest of the table.

Any help is appreciated!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Dimension of Measurement}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-6} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3}  \tabularnewline
\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Dimension of Sample}}} & \textbf{1} & \shortstack{P10\\No of fractures\\per unit length\\of borehole} & \shortstack{P11\\Length of\\fractures per\\unit length} &  &  & \textbf{\shortstack{Linear\\Measures}}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-7}

 & \textbf{2} & \shortstack{P20\\No of fractures\\per unit\\area} & \shortstack{P21\\Length of\\fractures per\\unit area} & \shortstack{P22\\Area of\\fractures per\\unit area} &  & \textbf{\shortstack{Areal\\Measures}}\tabularnewline
\cline{2-7}

 & \textbf{3} & \shortstack{P30\\No of fractures\\per unit\\volume} &  & \shortstack{P32\\Area of\\fractures per\\unit volume} & \shortstack{P33\\Volume of\\fractures per\\unit volume} & \textbf{\shortstack{Volumetric\\Measures}}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \textbf{Density} &  & \textbf{Intensity} & \textbf{Porosity} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\tabularnewline
\cline{3-6} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With the aid of the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package (provides `>` and `<` syntax) and the own defined macro `\mystack` you can get there quite easily.

Note, that the whole table is to wide for the standard `report` margins. I did not try to correct that. (Orienting the table to landscape would help here.)

Notes:

- You can get left-alined text in `\shortstack` with

  ```
  \shortstack[l]{…}
  ```
- There a few other ways to get multiple lines in one  cell:

  - [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell)
  - [How to break a line in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table)
  - [Newline in a table cell which is centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38924/newline-in-a-table-cell-which-is-centered)

### Code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,multirow,array}
\newcommand*{\mystack}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\bfseries}c|c|c|c|c|>{\bfseries}c|} \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                    &   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Dimension of Measurement}}                                                                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}               \\ \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                    &   & \textbf{0}                                                      & \textbf{1}                                              & \textbf{2}                                            & \textbf{3}                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}               \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Dimension of Sample}}} & 1 & \mystack{P10\\ No of fractures\\ per unit length\\ of borehole} & \mystack{P11\\ Length of\\ fractures per\\ unit length} &                                                       &                                                         & \mystack[c]{Linear\\ Measures}     \\ \cline{2-7}
                                                                            & 2 & \mystack{P20\\ No of fractures\\ per unit\\ area}               & \mystack{P21\\ Length of\\ fractures per\\ unit area}   & \mystack{P22\\ Area of\\ fractures per\\ unit area}   &                                                         & \mystack[c]{Areal\\ Measures}      \\ \cline{2-7}
                                                                            & 3 & \mystack{P30\\ No of fractures\\ per unit\\ volume}             &                                                         & \mystack{P32\\ Area of\\ fractures per\\ unit volume} & \mystack{P33\\ Volume of\\ fractures per\\ unit volume} & \mystack[c]{Volumetric\\ Measures} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                                                       & \textbf{Density}                                                &                                                         & \textbf{Intensity}                                    & \textbf{Porosity}                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}               \\ \cline{3-6}
\end{tabular}
```

### Output

[image: Output]