# How to create a table with some rows merged on the right column

Tags: tables

I want to create a table like

[image]

There are 2 cells in the 4th column which are merged vertically on the right side.

While it is easy to merge them on the left side using `multirow`, I'm at a loss on how to merge on the right side

Here is my source code (using [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls)):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
% Add the compsoc option for Computer Society conferences.
% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.eps}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
   \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}

 \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

    \ifCLASSINFOpdf
       \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

       \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.eps}
    \else
       \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
       \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
    \fi

    % correct bad hyphenation here
    \hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{multirow}

    \usepackage{subfigure}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Introduction}

    \section{xxx}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{0.6cm}|p{1cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{4cm}| }
    \hline
    {\fontsize{7}{60}\selectfont Source IP} & {\fontsize{7}{60}\selectfont Destination IP} & {\fontsize{7}{60}\selectfont CCN Name} & Example Application Scenarios \\
        \hline
    $\times$ & xx & xx& Content requester wants to hide its location/IP \\
        \hline
    dul & $\times$ & lus &  \multirow{2}{*}{Content requester wants to hide its location/IP} \\
        \cline{1-3}
    ddd & $\times$ & lus & \\
        \hline
    $\times$ & Lucus & lus & Content requester wants to hide its location/IP \\
        \hline
    $\times$ & Lucus & lus & Content requester wants to hide its location/IP \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{xxxx}
    \label{tab:header}
    \end{table}

    \begin{thebibliography}{1}

    \end{thebibliography}

    \end{document}
```

The result is the width of that two cells are not equal.

Comment: Have a look at the `multirow` package: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Rows_spanning_multiple_columns

Comment: the example only shows when the merged column is on the left. I don't know how to use multirow when the merged column is on the right, as in my case

Comment: `\multirow` goes in the upper cell, leave the lower one empty; it doesn't matter in what column you use it.

Comment: @user1944267 Please, add some code you already have for the merged rows in the first column, so it can be taken as a model for the solution. You asked "where's the `\hline`?", but nobody can know where you want it.

Comment: thx, pls see the update

Comment: So, the question seems to be "how to break a line in a table". The answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485/how-to-break-a-line-in-a-table works fine.

Comment: @nplait no, the problem is that two cells are not equally spaced, as http://s9.postimg.org/9no3ivyjj/table.png

Comment: I am sorry, but the code you provide above does not produce the result you show on my system; instead it produces this: http://s10.postimg.org/lzuut0rqh/image.png. I suspect there is something wrong with the code on your system, what is this "2*" in the cell?

Comment: @nplatis oh, strange, it becomes what you show in you picture. I don't know what the 2* represent. I just copied it from mannuals. But you see, the space is still unequal, and there is no line break

Comment: I suspect the "2*" was due to some spelling mistake while copying. Please be more careful... Did you try the solution that I linked to above? Include the content of your cell in a `\parbox` as instructed. And what spacing is still unequal?

Comment: \parbox makes things even messy, and the compilation failed. I think the problem is on how to properly use `multirow`.

Answer (score 3):

@egreg deserves the glory. Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
a1 & a2 & a3 & a4\\ \hline
b1 & b2 & b3 & \multirow{2}{*}{bc4}\\ \cline{1-3}
c1 & c2 & c3 & \\ \hline
d1 & d2 & d3 & d4
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: where is the `\hline` ?

Comment: Horizontal lines are easy, you already got them, too. But that seems to not be your actual problem. Please ask specific questions in order to get good answers...

Comment: pls see the pic, http://s9.postimg.org/9no3ivyjj/table.png. these two cells are not equally spaced

Comment: @user1944267 I think you might update your question and include a [Minimal Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produced this picture. I believe that after you do so, the problem will get solved in no time.

Comment: yes, I have included an MWE, pls see the update

Comment: Sorry, this is not a *Minimal* example... You could remove too many things and still demonstrate your issue.

Comment: I think I have removed many things. If I continue to remove, I'm not sure whether I remove the lines where problem arises.

Comment: Well, you remove and simplify one thing at a time, until you remove something that "breaks" your problem. For example, section headings and bibliography, as well as some `if` statements could surely be removed without harm.

Comment: I have updated the MWE, is it OK or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.6cm}|p{1cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{4cm}| }
\hline
{\fontsize{7}{60}\selectfont Source IP} & {\fontsize{7}{60}\selectfont Destination IP} & {\fontsize{7}{60}\selectfont CCN Name} & Example Application Scenarios \\
\hline
$\times$ & v & v & Content requester wants to hide its location/IP \\
\hline
dul & $\times$ & lus &  \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{4cm}{Content requester wants to hide its location/IP}} \\
\cline{1-3}
ddd & $\times$ & lus & \\
\hline
$\times$ & Lucus & lus & Content requester wants to hide its location/IP \\
\hline
$\times$ & Lucus & lus & Content requester wants to hide its location/IP \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{xxx }
\label{tab:header}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please update tyour previous answer if you need to offer alternatives

Comment: thanks. if I put a lot of words in: \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{4cm}{ `I put a lot of words here`}}. it will overlap the below cells. how to deal with this?