# Write on the line that has been returned

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I can not solve a small problem, starting from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10370) solution, I have done the table below but now I would like to write a word on each column with the type *first* and *second* in ***italics***.

For example the word **here** for *second* of type 1. But I don't know how to do it for all columns.

I have done this:

```latex
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}p{0.5cm}}
    type &  1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{1}
    \newline \small{\textit{first}} & \\
    \newline \small{\textit{second}} &     here\\
    \textbf{2}  
    \newline \small{first}} &  \\
    \textbf{3} 
    \newline \small{\textit{first}} &  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I would like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

If I understood you correctly, than you like to have the following table:

[image]

It can be simple set as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\small}p{1.5cm} *{3}{>{\sffamily}p{0.5cm}} }
\normalsize{type}   & 1     & 2     & 3     \\
    \hline
\textbf{1}          &       &       &       \\
\emph{first}        & here  & here  & here  \\
\emph{second}       & here  & here  & here  \\
\textbf{2}          &       &       &       \\
first               & here  & here  & here  \\
\textbf{3}          &       &       &       \\
\emph{first}        & here  & here  & here  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much ! I would never have found it on my own. Just how to set the normal latex font for words `here` (no helvetica)?

Comment: Oh yes to remove just `>{\sffamily}`. Thanks again a lot !

Comment: @Ted, I only try to replicate your second image in question. I'm glad, that you already solved problem with fonts. Happy TeXing :-)